# Expression to count records based on criteria in another table MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have two tables: customer and company. They are distantly linked via keys and I want to count how many customers are with one company. E.g.:

| Company | Customers |
| --- | --- |
| A | Customer1 |
| A | Customer2 |
| A | Customer3 |
| B | Customer4 |
| B | Customer5 |

So say I wanted to count the number of customers with company A, what expression should I use to calculate this figure as an alias?

Answer (score 0):

A simple query will do:

```sql
Select
    Company.Name,
    Customers.Count(*) As CustomerCount
From
    Company
Inner Join
    Customer ON Company.Id = Customer.CompanyId
Group By
    Customer.Name
```